# Usuário acessar site com nome dele no link

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema Web em PHP e MYSQL que possui cadastro de usuários. Os usuários se cadastram e acessam o sistema, sendo redirecionados para um painel: nomedosite.com/painel.

O que preciso é que para cada usuário que se cadastrar no sistema, ele possa acessar seu painel de forma mais intuitiva. Por exemplo, João Yoko se cadastrou e criou o nome de usuario como yokojoao. Assim ele poderia acessar o painel dele através da url: nomedosite.com/yokojoao. E cada usuario dessa forma.

Nunca criei algo relacionado. Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Isso daí você pode fazer de duas maneiras. Uma delas é usar arquivos .htaccess para redirecionar cada usuário para um link específico de acordo com o parâmetro.

A outra maneira é usar o .htaccess para identificar todo o parâmetro depois da `/` como um `$_GET` e ai na sua aplicação você pega o valor o indice dele que viraria algo `$_GET['yokojoao']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Developer, 
Uma forma de fazer isso que deseja é usar [URLs Amigáveis](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) como o [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) do apache, capturar requisições e passar elas a um arquivo, como a maior parte dos frameworks em PHP faz hoje em dia.

Assim quando um usuário acessar por exemplo `nomedosite.com/yokojoao` ele vai estar acessando `nomedosite.com/index.php` passando `yokojoao` como parametro, que o seu script PHP pode tratar para identificar o usuário.

Vale lembrar que nesse esquema de URL tudo o que for passado após o `nomedosite.com/` seria enviado como parametro para o script.

Caso esteja usando Apache e ele esteja com o mod_rewrite ativo você deve ter na raiz do site um arquivo chamado `.htaccess`, sim .htaccess, sem nada antes do ponto e sem extensão depois do access.

O conteúdo do arquivo pode ser algo como:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^busca/(.*)$ ./buscar.php?query=$1 
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)*$ ./login.php?username=$1
```

Neste caso os dois RewriteCond informam que condições disparam as regras abaixo, abaixo há duas regras, eu coloquei uma de busca para mostrar como você poderia continuar com algumas páginas após o /, caso esta regra não existisse o `/busca` seria entendido como nome de usuário.

O script acima redireciona qualquer `nomedosite.com/usuario` para `/login.php` passando o username como $_GET['username'] e caso algué busque `nomedosite.com/busca/algumacoisa` ele passa $_GET['query'] com valor de alguma coisa para `./buscar.php`